# How to treat new users

Tags: discussion

I know I've seen many instances where a user on PSE will welcome a new user, whether after a first question or answer, in the comments.  Is there any recommended way or standard for this procedure?

*Note: I'm not sure whether this has been posted in another form, though I've looked*

Comment: Personally I try to make welcome comments say more than just "welcome", e.g. "welcome, nice question" or "welcome, but this answer doesn't seem to be right" or whatever. The consensus on a different SE can be found at [this link](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6422/should-we-begin-flagging-welcome-messages-as-too-chatty), but we don't necessarily have to do the same here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends on the first appearance of the new user. If (s)he is just posting nicely within the guidelines of the site, just friendly welcome, congratulate to the posting etc.

If something in the posting is *not ideal*, welcome friendly and politely point out the issue. As a request, not as criticism!

If you can provide additional information like *rand al'thor* suggested, it is great. It establishes some more 'personal' connection (which makes newcomers feel at home).

Answer (score 4):

No special process needed, just be welcoming and friendly.